# The image wont change, how would I refresh the panel so it does?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, imageicon

When a certain event happens, I want the image to change but it does not occur.
Here is the code:

```
game.add(bbol);
if (flashed == 1) {
   bbol.setIcon(bboH);
} else {
}
```

Do I need to refresh the `game` panel?

**edit:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class BeeBee extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("BB8 Says");
    private JPanel game;
    private JPanel menu;
    ImageIcon bbegif = new ImageIcon("tumblr_o0c57n9gfv1tha1vgo1_r3_250.gif");
    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
    public int flashed = 0, glowTime, dark, ticks, indexPattern;
    public boolean creatingPattern = true;  
    public ArrayList<Integer> pattern;
    public Random random;
    private boolean gameOver;
    public int counter;
    public int temp;
    public int score;
    //these are the images, replace them if you like
    public ImageIcon bbb = new ImageIcon("bbb.gif");
    public JLabel bbbl = new JLabel(bbb);
    public ImageIcon bbbH = new ImageIcon("bbbH.gif");
    public ImageIcon bbg = new ImageIcon("bbg.gif");
    public JLabel bbgl = new JLabel(bbg);
    public ImageIcon bbgH = new ImageIcon("bbgH.gif");
    public ImageIcon bbgr = new ImageIcon("bbgr.gif");
    public JLabel bbgrl = new JLabel(bbgr);
    public ImageIcon bbgrH = new ImageIcon("bbgrH.gif");
    public ImageIcon bbo = new ImageIcon("bbor.gif");
    public JLabel bbol = new JLabel(bbo);
    public  ImageIcon bboH = new ImageIcon("bborH.gif");
    public  ImageIcon unhap = new ImageIcon("unhap.gif");
    public  JLabel unhapl = new JLabel(unhap);
    //these are the images, replace them if you like
    public BeeBee()
    {
        mainmenu();
    }
    public void start()
    {

    random = new Random();
    pattern = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    indexPattern = 0;
    dark = 2;
    flashed = 0;
    ticks = 0;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    ticks++;

    if (ticks % 20 == 0)
    {
        flashed = 0;

        if (dark >= 0)
        {
            dark--;
        }}

    if (creatingPattern)
    {
        if (dark <= 0)
        {
            if (indexPattern >= pattern.size())
            {
                flashed = random.nextInt(40) % 4 + 1;
                pattern.add(flashed);
                indexPattern = 0;
                creatingPattern = false;
            }
            else
            {
                flashed = pattern.get(indexPattern);
                indexPattern++;
            }

            dark = 2;
        }}
    else if (indexPattern == pattern.size())
    {
        creatingPattern = true;
        indexPattern = 0;
        dark = 2;
    }}
public void mainmenu()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
    start();
    timer.start();
    frame.setSize(WIDTH +7, HEIGHT +30);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    menu = new JPanel();
    game = new JPanel();
    menu.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    game.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    JButton button = new JButton("Start");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            frame.setContentPane(game);
            frame.invalidate();
            frame.validate();
        };
    });

    menu.add(button);
    gamme();
    frame.add(menu);
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}

public void gamme()
{
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 5);
    bbol.setBorder(border);
    bbgl.setBorder(border);
    bbgrl.setBorder(border);
    bbbl.setBorder(border);
    game.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    game.add(bbol);
    game.add(bbgl);
    game.add(bbgrl);
    game.add(bbbl);

}
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    new BeeBee();
}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{
    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();

    if (!creatingPattern && !gameOver)
    {
        if (x>0 && x<WIDTH/2 && y>0 && y<HEIGHT/2)
        {
            flashed = 1;
            ticks = 1;
            bbol.setIcon(bboH);
        }
        else if (x>WIDTH/2 && x<WIDTH && y>0 && y<HEIGHT/2)
        {
            flashed = 2;
            ticks = 1;
            bbgl.setIcon(bbgH);
        }
        else if (x>0 && x<WIDTH/2 && y>HEIGHT/2 && y<HEIGHT)
        {
            flashed = 3;
            ticks = 1;
            bbgrl.setIcon(bbgrH);
        }
        else if (x>WIDTH/2 && x<WIDTH && y>HEIGHT/2 && y<HEIGHT)
        {
            flashed = 4;
            ticks = 1;
            bbbl.setIcon(bbbH);
        }
        if (flashed != 0)
        {
            if (pattern.get(indexPattern)==flashed)
            {
                indexPattern++;
            }
            else
            {
                gameOver = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            start();
            gameOver = true;
        }}
    else if (gameOver)
    {
        start();
        gameOver = false;
    }
    if (flashed == 1) {
        bbol.setIcon(bboH);
    } else 
    {
        bbol.setIcon(bbo);
    }
 if (flashed == 2) {
        bbgl.setIcon(bbgH);
    } else 
    {
        bbgl.setIcon(bbg);
    }
 if (flashed == 3) {
        bbgrl.setIcon(bbgrH);
    } else 
    {
        bbgrl.setIcon(bbgr);
    }
 if (flashed == 4) {
        bbbl.setIcon(bbbH);
    } else 
    {
        bbbl.setIcon(bbb);
    }
    game.repaint();  
}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
{}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
{}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
{}
```

}

Comment: Please create and post your [mcve] so we can answer without guessing. What event for instance is triggering this change? Where is your event handling code -- your listener?

Answer (score 3):

`setIcon(...)` should be adequate to change the image in a JLabel. I question how you're adding the JLabel and when. If you're adding the component during program run, you're going to have to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container, the JPanel that is accepting the new JLabel. Usually it's better to add the JLabel at program start up and not have to worry about such issues. A

Also, **what** event is triggering this change? Your question and code are not adequate for us to determine this. Something in the back of my mind is worrying me that you've not yet written an event listener since we don't see any code above to suggest that the above code is present within a listener. Please clarify.

If still stuck, create and post your valid [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

You've still not posted a valid [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and so we still have to guess (please read the link),

But in your MouseListener, you're changing the state of the flashed field, **but you're not calling any code that will change the image**. I *suspect* that the critical code you've posted:

```
if (flashed == 1) 
{
     bbol.setIcon(bboH);
} else {
}
```

is present in your GUI creation code. If so, this is called once and only once, and will only use the original value of flashed. If you change the value of the flashed field, this code will not be magically re-called, but instead **you must call it yourself**. In other words, this code should be in the MouseListener.

Again, if you need more help, please do post a valid [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code posted here as code-formatted text, that we can actually compile and run.

Also, if you want a *blinking* icon, then you're going to need tp create and use a Swing Timer, one that swaps the icons every xxx milliseconds.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlinkingIcon extends JPanel {
    private static final int IMG_WIDTH = 200;
    private static final int GAP = 8;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 100;

    // index into icons array
    private int iconIndex = 0;

    // array of image icons
    private Icon[] icons = new Icon[2];

    // JLabel that displays the icons
    private JLabel mainLabel = new JLabel();

    // Swing Timer that when started swaps the icons 
    private Timer flashingTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());

    public BlinkingIcon() {
        // fill icons array with icons
        icons[0] = createIcon(Color.WHITE);
        icons[1] = createIcon(Color.RED);

        // add the first icon to the JLabel
        mainLabel.setIcon(icons[iconIndex]);

        // add the JLabel to the main JPanel, the GUI
        add(mainLabel);

        // add a MouseListener to the JLabel
        // one that turns the flashing timer on and off
        mainLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (flashingTimer.isRunning()) {
                    flashingTimer.stop();
                } else {
                    flashingTimer.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // for this example, I will create a simple icon that's little more than
    // a color circle, but any icons would work
    private Icon createIcon(Color white) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(white);
        g2.fillOval(GAP, GAP, IMG_WIDTH - 2 * GAP, IMG_WIDTH - 2 * GAP);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float) GAP));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawOval(GAP, GAP, IMG_WIDTH - 2 * GAP, IMG_WIDTH - 2 * GAP);
        g2.dispose();
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);        
        return icon;
    }

    // ActionListener for our flashingTimer
    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // add one to the iconIndex, the index to the icons array
            iconIndex++;
            iconIndex %= icons.length; // set to 0 if it reaches length of array
            mainLabel.setIcon(icons[iconIndex]); // swap the icon!            
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        BlinkingIcon mainPanel = new BlinkingIcon();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Blinking Icon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Regarding your posted code, you have MouseListener code but add it to no component, and listeners only work if you attach them to something, for example

```
game.addMouseListener(this);
```

Comment: would that be frame.repaint() or game.repaint()

Comment: @WillA: no, you shouldn't need this. Again, please please please clarify your question. Please post more pertinent code. Please let's not be forced to guess what is wrong with code not shown -- a **very** frustrating game.

Comment: @WillA: also please let us know **what** event you're listening to -- an ActionListener added to a JButton? An ActionLister added to a Swing Timer? A MouseListener added to another component?

Comment: @WillA: your mouse listener changes flashed but does not change the image icon. See edits

Comment: But as flashed changes, it affects the if statement, changing the icon

Comment: @WillA: are you seeing any changes? Is the icon visibly changing? If so, then your problem is solved. If not, then believe what I'm gelling you: that if block will not be re-called magically. You the coder has to call it.

Comment: @WillA: see my code above. For something like this, I create simple icons just for demo purposes.

Comment: I am not sure to make the icons like hop you did, i onlu know how to use ImageIcon

Comment: And for the blinking, the game is a copy of Simon (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YhVyt4q5HI) so I want the flashing to look like that

Comment: @WillA: then I am 100% sure that you will want to use a Swing Timer. It won't look exactly like my demo code above, but instead will go through your own ArrayList of colors or positions.

Comment: @WillA: but that's not the issue for your main question. Again your problem is that you've been stuck in magical thinking that changing the state of a field will cause the if block to be called again. The solution is to understand why this thinking is wrong, and to instead swap the icon in your listener code. End of story.

Comment: @WillA: again, no. Just swapping icons is all that is needed. Have you compiled and run my example program above? If not, please do so, and then click on the GUI that is created to see the demo. Do you see a call to `repaint()` in any of the code in my demo? Nope.

Comment: @WillA: notice the main difference between the code that I've posted vs. the code that you've posted: You can copy and run my code, and modify it to experiment with it, and see how and why it works. No one can copy and then compile and run your code as is, and so you show us the snippets and tell us that it doesn't work, and we can't do a thing about it or tell you why it does not work. If you still need help, then please follow through on the request made multiple times in this question -- that you create and post a *valid* [mcve] similar to what I've posted.

Comment: @WillA: Yes, I'm asking you to create and post a small new program, but I'm not asking for any more effort than I've already given in trying to answer your question, and so surely you can't think that I'm asking too much of you.

Comment: I think that I have cut it down to the bare minimum, I will edit the post

Comment: @WillA: thank you, but still I will ask you to either create your icons as I show above, or use online images obtained via URL. Otherwise if I run your code, I will get a NullPointerException. Probably the easiest for you is  to create a URL based image via `new URL(stringToImagePath)`, and then `ImageIO.read(myUrl)`.

Comment: `public URL bbb = new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png");
 public JLabel bbbl = ImageIO.read(bbb);` can you change this to be right

Comment: @WillA: Please let me know when you've made the edits to your posted code, and have tested it.

Comment: @WillA: You've got a MouseListener that you add to no component, and you've got an ActionListener that you add to no component, and so it should come as no surprise that you're not seeing any behaviors. These are proof reading errors that you should find before posting the code.

Comment: @WillA: I take back the ActionLIstener business as you are using it in the Timer, but you're still never adding a MouseListener to anything. No `game.addMouseListener(this);` for instance. Myself, I'd add a separate MouseListener to each JLabel and not to the game JPanel.

Comment: I have now got the image changing, however it is only for the top left image, do you want me to post my edits

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132116/discussion-on-answer-by-hovercraft-full-of-eels-the-image-wont-change-how-would).